# Dynamic variable based on previous month in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to change dynamically for below URL.

e.g let's say if I run the script in february, the url would be like below such as m-1-2023.

or if I run the script in march, the url would be like m-2-2023.

if I run the script in january 2023, the url would be like m-12-2022.

and so on.

As summary , it will be the previous month.

My URL:

```
https://app.contoso.com/api/v1/reports/billing/aws?filter%5Bdate_range%5D=m-1-2023
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.3) to get a DateTime object, which has support for date arithmetics and formatting. Get last month by adding -1 months and format with .Net [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) Like so,

```
$d = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("M-yyyy")
$url = "https://app.contoso.com/api/v1/reports/billing/aws?filter%5Bdate_range%5D=m-" + $d
# output
https://app.contoso.com/api/v1/reports/billing/aws?filter%5Bdate_range%5D=m-1-2023
```